# Matching query does not exist - 2 slugs

Tags: python, html, css, django-models

First of all, sorry for the inconvenience and the mess, I've just started to use Django and it's my first post here.

What happens is, I have to use 2 slugs (slugfrance and slugslovenia) and slugfrance is trying to use the database of slugslovenia (I believe). When I try to enter in the posts (=experiences) for Slovenia I have no problem, but for France it tells me:

> SloveniaExperience matching query does not exist.

My **requirements** are:

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==1.8
django-countries==5.3.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
psycopg2==2.7.5
whitenoise==4.0
```

My code is the following:

**For models.py**

```
class SloveniaExperience(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        exchange_country = CountryField(default='DEFAULT VALUE')
        category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='DEFAULT VALUE')
        text = models.TextField(default='DEFAULT VALUE')
        slugslovenia = models.SlugField(default='default-value')
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(
                default=timezone.now)
        published_date = models.DateField(
                blank=True, null=True)
        def publish(self):
            self.published_date = timezone.now()
            self.save()
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

>class FranceExperience(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        exchange_country = CountryField(default='DEFAULT VALUE')
        category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='DEFAULT VALUE')
        slugfrance = models.SlugField(default='default-value')
        text = models.TextField(default='DEFAULT VALUE')
        created_date = models.DateTimeField(
                default=timezone.now)
        published_date = models.DateField(
                blank=True, null=True)
        def publish(self):
            self.published_date = timezone.now()
            self.save()
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

**For urls.py**

```
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^experiences-asia/$', views.experiencesasia, name="experiencesasia"),
    url(r'^experiences-europe/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.blogslovenia, name="blogslovenia"),
    url(r'^experiences-europe/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.blogfrance, name="blogfrance"),
    url(r'^experiences-europe/$', views.experienceseurope, name="experienceseurope"),
    url(r'^engineering/$', views.engineering, name="engineering"),
    url(r'^talks/$', views.talks, name="talks"),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name="about"),
]
```

**For views.py:**

```
def blogslovenia(request, slug):
    sloveniaexperiences = SloveniaExperience.objects.get(slugslovenia=slug)
    return render(request, 'blogslovenia.html', {'sloveniaexperiences': sloveniaexperiences})

def blogfrance(request, slug):
    franceexperiences = FranceExperience.objects.get(slugfrance=slug)
    return render(request, 'blogfrance.html', {'franceexperiences': franceexperiences})
```

I call them in the HTML using:

> href="{% url 'blogslovenia' slug=sloveniaexperience.slugslovenia %}" 
>   href="{% url 'blogfrance' slug=franceexperience.slugfrance %}"

Maybe someone can help me... I have already made makemigrations and migrate in order to update the database but nothing. Thanks for reading!

Comment: I don't understand why you have two identical models. I also don't understand how you expect Django to tell the difference between views.blogslovenia and views.blogfrance when they both have the exact same URL pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you try to access the view `blogfrance` from a URL, you always end up to `blogslovenia` because they both have the exact same url pattern and I guess since slovenia is listed first it goes to slovenia. So when you enter a slug for france, the `SloveniaExperience`.

As @Daniel Roseman mentioned, there is no point having these two models, just merge them in one with an extra field, something like this:

```
country_choices = (
    ("slovenia", "Slovenia"),
    ("france", "France"),
)

class FranceExperience(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exchange_country = CountryField(default='DEFAULT VALUE')
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='DEFAULT VALUE')
    slug = models.SlugField(default='default-value')
    text = models.TextField(default='DEFAULT VALUE')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=country_choices) # Added field
```

Then you can have one view and one url.